# Error while creating C++ array

Tags: c++, ns-3

```
#include "connection.h"


 ConnectionType[] ConnectionArray = new ConnectionType[NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS];
```

I get 2 errors

1. Error: expected an identifier
2. Error: expected a ';'

I have

```
class ConnectionType {
public:
  Ptr<Socket> txMstrSocPtr; /// Pointer to Master tx socket
  Ptr<Socket> rxMstrSocPtr; /// Pointer to Master rx socket
  Ptr<Socket> txSlavSocPtr; /// Pointer to Slave tx socket
  Ptr<Socket> rxSlavSocPtr; /// Pointer to Slave rx socket

  //ConnectionType();
  //~ConnectionType();

  void rxMstrCallBack(Ptr<Socket> socket);
  void rxSlavCallBack(Ptr<Socket> socket);
};

Defined in connection.h
```

Do you have any idea why I get these 2 errors?

Comment: When was `#includ`ing of `.h` files introduced in C#?

Comment: Is this C# or C++? C# has no `#include`.

Comment: It's C++ Sorry but written to .cc file is it possible.

Comment: This isn't C++.  Is it C++/CLI or C++/CX?   (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX )

Comment: It's NS3 package on Windows and I'm trying to add some code, it is C like, but I keep getting strange error messages

Comment: What compiler do you use?   Could you provide the full and complete error message

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012, and this error I get in the editor even before compiling

Comment: @Fouda - Why does your syntax look like Java or C#?  C++ is neither of these languages.  And why can't it be just `ConnectionType ConnectionArray[NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration syntax needs to be changed to:

```
ConnectionType* ConnectionArray = new ConnectionType[NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS];
```

Comment: If `NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS` is a constant, there is no need to create this dynamically and introduce a possible memory leak.

Comment: it's not a constant it's #define in another h file not shown hear

Comment: Now I get another error error C2039: 'Unref' : is not a member of 'ConnectionType'

Comment: I think it's due to using Ptr<> (Smart Pointer) inside my Class, do u have any idea how to fix it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie makes a great point: if you can get away with a static array, then do that so you don't have to worry about releasing that memory when you're done with it. Something like this: ConnectionType connectionArray[NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS];. Another small note on convention: variables are usually named with a lower-case first letter and functions are usually named with an upper-case first letter so you can quickly tell them apart.

Comment: @Fouda - A #define *is* constant, unless the #define uses a runtime expression in some form.  Show us this `#define` -- if it's as simple as `#define NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS  10` or something similar to that, then it is a constant.